# pygame circle not changing

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, fill

I finally got the collision down so that when my mouse is hovering over the circles and you click the left mouse button, It fills in. It changes going up, but going down it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
# Imports a library of functions!
import pygame
import random
# Initializes the game engine
pygame.init()
# Defines the colors
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  3, 255,   3)
# Controls the width of the circle
width_1 = 2
width_2 = 2
width_3 = 2
width_4 = 2
# Un-fills circles
filled_1 = False
filled_2 = False
filled_3 = False
filled_4 = False
# Sets the height and width of the screen
size = [720, 575] 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
# Loops until the user clicks the close button
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# While loop
while not done:
    # Leaves the fps at 30
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # If user did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
             done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            # Finds where you clicked            
            x, y = event.pos
            # Check if mouse was over it
            if circle_1.collidepoint(x, y):
                # Lets the circle draw
                filled_1 = True
                width_1 = 0
                if filled_1 == True:
                    circle_1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 230], 7, width_1)
            elif circle_2.collidepoint(x, y):
                # Lets the circle draw
                filled_2 = True
                width_2 = 0
                if filled_2 == True:
                    circle_2 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 260], 7, width_2)               
            elif circle_3.collidepoint(x, y):
                # Lets the circle draw
                filled_3 = True
                width_3 = 0
                if filled_3 == True:
                    circle_3 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 260], 7, width_3)
            elif circle_4.collidepoint(x, y):
                # Lets the circle draw
                filled_4 = True
                width_4 = 0
                if filled_4 == True:
                    circle_4 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 260], 7, width_4)
    # Cleans the screen and sets the screen background
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    # Circles
    circle_1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 230], 7, width_1)
    circle_2 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 260], 7, width_2)
    circle_3 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 290], 7, width_3)
    circle_4 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 320], 7, width_4)
    if filled_1 == True:
        filled_2 = False
        filled_3 = False
        filled_4 = False
        width_2 = 2
        width_3 = 2
        width_4 = 2
    elif filled_2 == True:
        filled_1 = False
        filled_3 = False
        filled_4 = False
        width_1 = 2
        width_3 = 2
        width_4 = 2
    elif filled_3 == True:
        filled_1 = False
        filled_2 = False
        filled_4 = False
        width_1 = 2
        width_2 = 2
        width_4 = 2
    elif filled_4 == True:
        filled_1 = False
        filled_2 = False
        filled_3 = False
        width_1 = 2
        width_2 = 2
        width_3 = 2
    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Just run this code and see what happens, its pretty hard to explain.

Comment: A *minimal*, *runnable* sample would do wonders.

Comment: It is runnable, Im just showing the code that Is important

Comment: It might be runnable for you, but it's not for me. Get rid of *everything* that you don't need for the problem to show up (if you only need one circle, only keep one; if you only need that part of the `if`, make it *always* true and remove the check) but keep *everything* that **needs** to be there (keep the event loop and display updating in, for example).

Comment: Okay, now I understand. I'll get right to it

Comment: Great, thanks! (If you comment when you're done I'll get a reminder in my notifications.)

Comment: Okay, I got it. But there is an indentation error that didn't make sense to me. It should make sense to you

Comment: We're getting there! There's more than just a single indentation error. You should try and make sure code is runnable before posting it. I added some indents and changed the `elif` to `if`, so now it runs. I also removed the fullscreen mode as it's extra stuff that is unhelpful (it changed my screen resolution!). But the code isn't acting quite like you said it would (the circles don't stay highlighted), so you'll need to change it so it does.

Comment: It does in the main program, but I can't figure out how to replicate it

Comment: That's good! Now you know *where* the bug might be, so you can start to *debug* it! Start from the full code, with the problem. *Slowly* remove the unimportant parts until you get to the code in this question. Somewhere it will switch between the behaviours. That's where the problem (or *a problem*) is. Then you can refine your question.

Comment: When I remove keypressed it stops staying filled in. It doesn't make sense at all

Comment: Think about when you're drawing, when `fill` is called, etc.

Comment: elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # If user pressed a key. Then instead of circles being filled in, they only are filled in when I click, Im gonna put the code up there to show you

Comment: After you run the new code I posted you need to click any key for it to work, then try removing pygame.keydown.

Comment: Fixed it again, I see what you mean by fill. now it stays filled in. The only issue now is un-filling the circles

Comment: Another fix, run the code in the question and click on different circles, it fills on the way up but not on the way down.

Comment: fyi: this question is discussed on meta. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256161/low-quality-question-but-op-willing-to-learn?cb=1

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let's assume that the second one is clicked, so

```
filled_1 = False
filled_2 = True
filled_3 = False
filled_4 = False
```

Then you click the third. Thus,

```
filled_1 = False
filled_2 = True
filled_3 = True
filled_4 = False
```

You then have:

```
screen.fill(GREEN)

circle_1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 230], 7, width_1)
circle_2 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 260], 7, width_2)
circle_3 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 290], 7, width_3)
circle_4 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 320], 7, width_4)
```

which will (tempoarily) draw *two* black circles.

You *then* do:

```
if filled_1 == True:
    # Not run
```

and then

```
elif filled_2 == True:
    filled_1 = False
    filled_3 = False
    filled_4 = False
    width_1 = 2
    width_3 = 2
    width_4 = 2
```

so now

```
filled_1 = False
filled_2 = True
filled_3 = False
filled_4 = False
```

This isn't wanted! Now

```
elif filled_3 == True:
    # Not run
elif filled_4 == True:
    # Not run
```

So clicking the third didn't work! This is because **you don't store the *order*, which is needed**.

I suggest moving this setting-to-false into the part inside the click handler:

```
if circle_1.collidepoint(x, y):
    # Lets the circle draw
    filled_1 = True
    width_1 = 0

    filled_2 = False
    filled_3 = False
    filled_4 = False
    width_2 = 2
    width_3 = 2
    width_4 = 2

    if filled_1 == True:
        circle_1 = pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, [250, 230], 7, width_1)

# ... etc ...
```

That works beautifully.

Now, there is still a problem. If on the first iteration there *was* an event, `circle_1` would not be defined. This would crash the program. You should define the circles *first*.

---

Some code advice.

Instead of

```
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  3, 255,   3)
```

use

```
pygame.Color("black")
pygame.Color(3, 255, 3)
```

They exist *for you*!

Instead of having

```
thing_1 = ...
thing_2 = ...
...

other_thing_1 = ...
other_thing_2 = ...
...
```

have a list of dictionaries:

```
circles = [
    {
        "thing": ...,
        "other_thing": ...
    }, {
        "thing": ...,
        "other_thing": ...
    },
    ...
]
```

where you use `circles[1]["thing"]` instead of `thing_1`.

This allows you to "simplify" to:

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

circles = [
    {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 230]
    }, {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 260]
    }, {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 290]
    }, {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 320]
    },
]

size = [720, 575] 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    done = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while not done:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 done = True

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                x, y = event.pos

                # Check if mouse was over it
                if circles[1]["bounding box"].collidepoint(x, y):
                    # Lets the circle draw
                    circles[1]["filled"] = True
                    circles[1]["width"] = 0

                    circles[2]["filled"] = False
                    circles[3]["filled"] = False
                    circles[4]["filled"] = False
                    circles[2]["width"] = 2
                    circles[3]["width"] = 2
                    circles[4]["width"] = 2

                    if circles[1]["filled"] == True:
                        circles[1]["bounding box"] = pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color("black"), [250, 230], 7, circles[1]["width"])

                ...
    # Cleans the screen and sets the screen background
    screen.fill(pygame.Color(3, 255, 3))
    # Circles
    circles[1]["bounding box"] = pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color("black"), circles[1]["position"], 7, circles[1]["width"])
    circles[2]["bounding box"] = pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color("black"), circles[2]["position"], 7, circles[2]["width"])
    circles[3]["bounding box"] = pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color("black"), circles[3]["position"], 7, circles[3]["width"])
    circles[4]["bounding box"] = pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color("black"), circles[4]["position"], 7, circles[4]["width"])
    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

That might not look simpler, but it allows you to use loops instead of specifying things *over and over*:

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

circles = [
    {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 230]
    }, {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 260]
    }, {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 290]
    }, {
        "width": 2,
        "filled": False,
        "position": [250, 320]
    },
]

size = [720, 575] 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not done:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            x, y = event.pos

            for circle in circles:
                # Check if mouse was over it
                if circle["bounding box"].collidepoint(x, y):
                    # Lets the circle draw
                    circle["filled"] = True
                    circle["width"] = 0

                    for othercircle in circles:
                        if othercircle is not circle:
                            othercircle["filled"] = False
                            othercircle["width"] = 2

                    if circle["filled"] == True:
                        circle["bounding box"] = pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color("black"), circle["position"], 7, circle["width"])

    # Cleans the screen and sets the screen background
    screen.fill(pygame.Color(3, 255, 3))
    # Circles
    for circle in circles:
        circle["bounding box"] = pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color("black"), circle["position"], 7, circle["width"])
    # Update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

With this design:

Q: What do you do to add another circle? 
A: You add it to `circles`.

Q: What do you do to make a circle larger? 
A: You increase its `size` property.

Q: What do you do to change the way collisions are checked for? 
A: You change the *one* place collisions are checked.

---

See the benefit? :)

Comment: Very straightforward and thanks for the extra advice. One question though, what does bounding box do?

Comment: `circles[X]["bounding box"]` is equivalent to your `circle_X`. So it's the `pygame.Rect` returned when you *draw* the circle. I called it `"bounding box"` because it's actually a square, not a circle like you said. If you make the circles larger, you can see that you can click outside the circle, because the square has corners outside of the circle.